# Просмотр видео с youtube android

Tags: java, android, youtube-android-api

Что нужно применить в `Android` проекте, чтобы реализовать просмотр канала `YouTube` в нем ?

Answer (score 2):

Без youtube api можно открыть так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/channel/" + channelName));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: тогда я просто вызову `YouTube` приложение. Вы можете рассказать о реализации с `YouTube API`, чтобы видео отображалось непосредственно в приложении ?

Comment: именно с youtube api работал очень давно. К сожалению исходники проекта не сохранились. Но думаю в инете много примеров